why lmkd socket use write , but not send , is it must communicate with block mode?
lmkd socket use write defaultly, so it will be blocked during sending socket data， can it modify MSG_DONTWAIT with send() API
static int ctrl_data_write(int dsock_idx, char* buf, size_t bufsz) {
    int ret = 0;
    ret = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(write(data_sock[dsock_idx].sock, buf, bufsz));
    if (ret == -1) {
        ALOGE("control data socket write failed; errno=%d", errno);
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        ALOGE("Got EOF on control data socket");
        ret = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

I test following patch ,it work also
static int ctrl_data_write(int dsock_idx, char* buf, size_t bufsz) {
int ret = 0;
ret = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(send(data_sock[dsock_idx].sock, buf, bufsz, MSG_DONTWAIT));

if (ret == -1) {
    ALOGE("control data socket write failed; errno=%d", errno);
} else if (ret == 0) {
    ALOGE("Got EOF on control data socket");
    ret = -1;
}

return ret;

}
